# Titanium - email attachment not being sent

Tags: email, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to send an email from a Titanium app and attach a PDF document, the PDF document shows in the email dialog but is not included when you send the email?

This is my code.

```
var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
emailDialog.subject = "Subject";
//emailDialog.toRecipients = ['foo@yahoo.com'];
emailDialog.messageBody = 'Body';
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('idata1.pdf');
emailDialog.addAttachment(f);
emailDialog.open();
}
```

Comment: Where is the file? Resources Folder, Application Folder, Data, Temp? It is importante due to each system have any folders (private or public) and protected. That route is relative and must be (minimum) at Resources Folder or same folder of js with that code ;)

Comment: I use this code to move the file before its used, i did get it working just had to use a 'file.read' 'command.function copyLocalFileToDocumentDir(filename,newfilename) {
 var resourceFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, filename + ".dat");
 var documentFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, newfilename + ".pdf");

 if (resourceFile.exists()) {
  Ti.API.info('File Exists in Resource Dir: ' + filename);
  var readContents = resourceFile.read();
  documentFile.write(readContents);
 }
};'

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is the only way to get the PDF to send in the email

```
var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
emailDialog.subject = "Subject";
emailDialog.messageBody = 'Body';
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "idata1.pdf");
if(file.exists()){
    emailDialog.addAttachment(file.read());
}else{
Ti.API.error('file does not exists');
}   
emailDialog.open();
```